# Отловить UnauthorizedAccessException при обходе папок

Tags: c#

Я создаю подпрограмму для своей основной. Её суть заключается в защите (шифровании) некоторых чувствительных данных от основной программы, её логов и прочих плюшек. Основная программа запускает дополнительную. Проблема в следующем методе:

```
public void encryptDirectory(string location, string password)
{

var validExtensions = new[]
{
".svlog", ".wtc", ".superad", ".passr"
};

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(location);
string[] childDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(location);
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
string extension = Path.GetExtension(files[i]);
if (validExtensions.Contains(extension))
{
EncryptFile(files[i], password);

}

}

for (int i = 0; i < childDirectories.Length; i++)

{

encryptDirectory(childDirectories[i], password);

}

}
```

Всё хорошо работает, если я использую папку в документах пользователя. Но было решено сделать поиск по всему диску C этих расширений. При этом папка может быть создана где угодно и называться как угодно. Проблемы начинаются, когда я попадаю, например, в папку Documents and settings - вылетает exception доступа к директории и программа падает на строке:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(location);
```

Была идея использовать конструкцию try {} catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) {} но как это сделать, чтобы программа затем продолжила поиск? В location лежит такой путь: C:\
Если не затруднит, объясните подробней как с этим бороться?
Метод вызывается так: encryptDirectory(EnPath, password); 
где string EnPath = "C:\";

Comment: Вам что нужно - просканировать системные папки с ограниченным доступом, или обойти их?

Comment: Нужно обойти их.

Comment: Просто перебрать все что есть на диске С . Если к чему-то нет доступа, то игнорировать и идти дальше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если просто тупо все перебрать, то вот такая небольшая модификация Вашего кода это сделает:

```
    public void encryptDirectory(string location, string password)
    {

        var validExtensions = new[]
        {
            ".svlog", ".wtc", ".superad", ".passr"
        };

        string[] files=null;

        try
        {
            files = Directory.GetFiles(location);
        }
        catch(UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            //Пишите если нужно что-то в log
        }

        if (files != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(files[i]);
                if (validExtensions.Contains(extension))
                {
                    EncryptFile(files[i], password);
                }
            }
        }


        string[] childDirectories = null;

        try
        {
            childDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(location);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            //Пишите если нужно что-то в log
        }

        if (childDirectories != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < childDirectories.Length; i++)
            {
                encryptDirectory(childDirectories[i], password);
            }
        }
    }
```

Ну и нужно помнить, что Вы ловите только один тип исключений, а при чтении каталогов и файлов могут возникнуть исключения других типов, которые Вы должны обработать. Где - это уже Вы должны решать сами, исходя из логики Вашего приложения.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую и отпишусь=)

Comment: Всё прописал - то что нужно. + добавил поиск любого исключения после перехвата доступа. Тогда, даже если где-то попадётся файл подобного расширения, то другой эксепшин не вылетит. catch (Exception e) {//любая другая ошибка}

Comment: Прошу прощения, я тут новичок. Подскажите как принять ответ и добавить Вам баллов?

Comment: Всё нашёл, нажал. Проверьте =)

Comment: @ANTARES, Вижу :) - я удалю ставшие ненужными комментарии, адресованные на Ваше прежнее имя :)